# Drawing a Tinted QPixmap using QPainter

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have a single-color transparent PNG loaded with a QPixmap, I want to draw this pixmap multiple times using different colors (e.g. once green, another yellow, etc). These QPixmaps are rendered through QPainter in the paintEvent function of a QWidget.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the pixmap into qimage and paint your own color .

1- Use **QImage::fill(DesiredColor)**

2- QPaintDevice  supports QImage so use **QPainter painter(&qImage);** // 8 bit will not support in paint event .

then recreate QPixmap with image using **QPixmap::fromImage(qImage);**